# config get * not working in redis 3.2.8

Tags: redis, redis-cli

```
>config get *

ERR unknown command 'config'
```

however, https://redis.io/commands/config-get says that the command is available since redis 2.0.
My redis_version : 3.2.8

P.S. I have just started learning redis.

Comment: how did you check the version of your redis server? are you sure you are accessing the one you think you should? are you running it locally?

Comment: >info server command gives me the version -- redis_version:3.2.8

Comment: I am running on redis server

Comment: are you running the redis server locally? are you suing `redis.conf` file?

Comment: No, its  remote.

Comment: Then I guess the `config` command has been disabled, by simply renaming it to something unguessable.

Comment: yeah, that seems to be only reason possible